# Put image inside form input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to put an svg image inside a bootstrap form input like this :

[image]

this is the html side :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="subscribe-wrapper subscribe2-wrapper mb-15">
    <div class="input-group">
      <img src="../../../assets/images/Combined Shape.svg" alt="">
      <input type="email" class="form-control email-input" placeholder="Votre email">

      <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn subscribe-btn type="submit">Souscrire</button>
      </span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**sass**

```
.email-input
  height: 50px
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px
::placeholder
  color: $primary-gray

.subscribe-btn 
  min-height: 50px
  border-radius:0 4px 4px 0
  background: $base-red
  color: #fff
  font-weight:600
```

I got this :

[image]

Should I create another white div next to the input or there is some way to do it with sass ?

Comment: you'll need to simulate an input, try adding a container that holds just the `img` and `input`, give this container a white background and borders and remove all background and borders from the input, that way the container will look like the input box, but with the image and the real input inside

Comment: try to wrap the image with an `input-group-prepend`

Answer (score 1):

The solution i've found is to add a relative position to the input and absolute position to the image and add some top and left %

```
.newsletter-icon
  position: absolute
  top: 30%
  left: 3%
  z-index: 2

.newsletter-form
  position: relative
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do it:

Either keep the image the place it is, and then make the icon absolute positioning while the container of the input is relative like so (with a little tweaks for SASS):

```
.input-group{
    position:relative;

    img{
       position:absolute;
       left:15px; //Make sure this is left from the border width + padding of input.
       top:calc(50% - 15px); //the 15px should be half of the height of the image. That way it'll be positioned in the middle of the input, regardless of the height.
    }

    input{
        padding-left:50px; //This needs to be the width of the icon + its left positioning + additional padding between the icon and the beginning of the words. 
    }
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that it's not really scalable. If you notice on bootstrap's site [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#multiple-addons), it outlines that anything prepending has a span and class associated to add additional styling. Because you're veering off of bootstrap in this styling, you should do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group has_icon icon_email">
    <input type="email" class="form-control email-input" placeholder="Votre email">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn subscribe-btn type="submit">Souscrire</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.input-group{

    &.has_icon{
        position:relative;

        input[type=email]{//Make sure to specify the type of input here, because if you do input type button, this will mess you up.
            padding-left:50px; //This needs to be the width of the icon + its left positioning + additional padding between the icon and the beginning of the words. 
        }
        &.icon_email:before{
            content:"";
            background-image:url(../../../assets/images/Combined Shape.svg);
            pointer-events: none; //You might not want the user to click the icon because it's on an input. Makes it easier to click the input
            position:absolute;
            left:15px; //Make sure this is left from the border width + padding of input.
            top:calc(50% - 15px); //the 15px should be half of the height of the image. That way it'll be positioned in the middle of the input, regardless of the height.
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this approach ensures that your other code that has `input-group`s wont get messed up from this code alone, since you're coding classes, which are repeatable and reusable. So the only time the icon will effect the input of text, email, etc. will be when you apply the additional class of `.has_icon`. You can tweak the class to what ever you want, or add more. Ideally you wouldn't do all in the same place, but this is to minimize my answer.